# Why do I need to use this in ES6 map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

From what I knew, ES6 map automatically binds to this.

```
                            {
                             cart.products ?
                                <span>
                                cart.products.map( product => {

                                  this.product  ?   //here
                                    <span>
                              blablabla
                                </span>
                                  :
                                  false
                                })
```

but somehow product is undefined here in the function unless I make it this.product, why is that?

Comment: MY bad. I should have tagged React. That's how react works. I don't like that down-vote for nothing.

Comment: bind  means it will be in context of react instead of the function

Answer (score 1):

I don't clearly understood your query, yet I suppose the problem may be because of the `{ }` you have added on `map()` function. If you use block within `map()` make sure you `return` something from that block.

When writing `map()` function if there is only a **single statement** you can **avoid using curly brackets** as it automatically returns the statement.

```
array.map(item => item+1)
```

If you are using curly brackets make sure you use **`return`** key word to return back the elements inside the block.

```
array.map(item => { return item+1 })
```

---

Coming back to your example, I think this should work fine,

```
{ 
    cart.products 
    ?  <span>
            cart.products.map(product => <span> { product } </span> )
       </span>
    :  false 
}
```

or

```
{ 
    cart.products 
    ?  <span>
            cart.products.map(product => { return <span> { product } </span> })
       </span>
    :  false 
}
```

I don't see any use of the condition check inside `map()` function as it is redundant.

Hope this helps! If not, ping me here with your query.